# Is this Postgres query not optimal?

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.2

I am facing an issue where the following query is taking a very long time to run in Postgres 9.2:

```
select coalesce(sum(col_a), 0) 
from table_a 
where tid not in ( 
    select distinct tid 
    from table_b 
    where col_b = 13 )
```

Note that `tid` is the primary key in `table_a`. For `table_b`, `tid` is indexed and references `table_a` as a foreign key.

The issue primarily happens when the disk is near full and some re-indexing is happening in the table. I am not a database expert, and I don't really understand what the issue could be.

Can some one please help understand the issue / tell me if there is a more optimum query?

Comment: do you have index on col_b? This is where seqscan is happening

Comment: No, there is no index on col_b

Comment: Maybe a left join or not exists has better performance? `select coalesce(sum(col_a), 0) from table_a left join table_b on table_a.tid = table_b.tid and table_b.column = 13 where table_b.tid is null` or  `select coalesce(sum(col_a), 0) from table_a where NOT EXISTS (select *
    from table_b 
    where col_b = 13 and table_b.tid = table_a.tid)`

Comment: `NOT EXISTS` is typically faster then `NOT IN` and the `distinct` in the sub-query is unnecessary

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but: Postgres 9.2 is [no longer supported](https://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/)  you should plan an upgrade as soon as possible.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name upgrade has already happened. This for some end-of-life products.

Comment: What do you mean by "not optimal"? What have you tried to debug the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would try with `NOT EXISTS` :

```
select coalesce(sum(a.col_a), 0) 
from table_a a
where not exists (select 1 from table_b b where b.tid = a.tid and b.col_b = 13);
```

Also, aggregation would also helpful :

```
select coalesce(sum(a.col_a), 0) 
from table_a a inner join
     table_b b
     on b.tid = a.tid
group by a.tid
having count(*) filter (where b.col_b = 13) = 0;
```

One more option is to use `left join` :

```
select coalesce(sum(a.col_a), 0) 
from table_a a left join
     table_b b
     on b.tid = a.tid and b.col_b = 13
where b.tid is null;
```

For optimal performance, index would helpful `table_a(tid, col_a)`, `table_b(tid, col_b)`

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend `NOT EXISTS` *with the right index*.  So, write the query as:

```
select coalesce(sum(col_a), 0) 
from table_a a
where not exists (select 1
                  from table_b b
                  where b.tid = a.tid and b.col_b = 13
                 );
```

The index that you want is on `table_b(tid, col_b)`:

```
create index idx_table_b_tid_col_b on table_b(id, col_b);
```